# Forcing Google Docs to update

Tags: google-docs, synchronization

I have shared a document and its public presentation is not quite the same as I see in the editor. Some equations fail in the public viewer and I need to tune them. This means a lot of edit and view iterations. Yet, there is a delay between document saved and updated in the public view.

Can I force the update?